# Plotting a binary matrix - R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, binary

I have a binary matrix, which the row names are usernames and col names are dates. How can I plot the data as explained in the example.

**Example:**

```
  2011-1-6  2011-1-9  2011-1-15  2011-2-19  Labels
A    1         0         0          1         1
B    0         1         1          1         2
C    1         1         0          0         3
```

In this case, the desired graph would be like the following:

[image]

Comment: Are `A`, `B`, `C` supposed to be `1`, `2`, `3`?

Comment: @MartinGal, Yes

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways but I want to encourage using tidy data and `ggplot2`. So assuming your matrix is named `mat`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# or simply just use: library(tidyverse)

mat %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(id=rownames(.),
         Labels = as.factor(Labels)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("2011")) %>%
  filter(value==1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=id, color=Labels)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

returns a plot similar to your desired output.

So what did we do?

1. Convert the matrix into a data.frame.
2. Add the row names a new column.
3. Reshape the data into a "long" format. This is necessary for `ggplot`to process the data.
4. Remove (`filter`) all `value == 0` rows, since only the `value == 1` rows should be plottet.
5. Finally use `ggplot` to plot the data as scatter plot (`geom_points`) with colors by Labels and rotated labels for the x-axis.

---

Data

```r
structure(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3), 
          .Dim = c(3L, 5L), 
          .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C"), 
                           c("2011-1-6", "2011-1-9", "2011-1-15", "2011-2-19", "Labels")))
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin Gal. If my user are divided into clusters (lets say 4 clusters), how can i have these dots into 4 different colors? The label of the clusters are inthe last cloumn

Comment: It's easier, if you show your data. The color is applied by `aes(..., color=[YOUR_COLUMN_NAME])`. But your data have to be in the correct shape/format.

Comment: I have tried the color command and I get different error. Would you please complete your answer in that regards (I edited my questions). Also, the labels of x-axis need to be vertical. Right now, they all overlapped. Thanks

Comment: @EsterSilva I adjusted my answer. You should get now different colors and rotated x-axis labels